# Hide divs with opacity:0.3 attribute

Tags: javascript

I need to hide a div (and children) that has "opacity:0.3". An example of one of the divs I want to remove is:

`<div id="mkey_1" class="btm1" style="border:2px ridge #5C0D12; opacity:0.3">`

While leaving this visible:

`<div id="mkey_1" class="btm1" style="border:2px ridge #5C0D12">`

This is one of the multiple things I've tried so far but I'm not getting anywhere:

```
var removeit = getAllElementsWithAttribute('opacity:0.3');
removeit.parentNode.removeChild(removeit);
```

I'm not sure if the colon breaks it or not...

Comment: where did you find that you should use getAllElementsWithAttribute ?

Comment: You are saying you want to hide the div and then you say you want it visible? Do you just want to remove the opacity when = .3?

Comment: I only want to remove the div if it has opacity 0.3. I have no idea if getAllElementsWithAttribute is the right function to use or not.

Answer (score 0):

I would use jQuery as it makes it very easy to select and manage DOM elements (plus much more).

In this case it should be enough to do:

```
$("div[style*='opacity:0.3']").remove();
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid jquery if possible but I will admit it does work nicely lol. Thanks